# Select Like in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou desenvolvendo uma rotina para padronizar as descrições em um  banco de dados Oracle. Para tanto estou varrendo toda a base de dados onde seleciono a descrição, extraio palavra por palavra e as comparo a um banco de dados. As palavras que não forem encontradas são apresentadas ao usuário que informa a palavra correta para aquele caso.

Após isso, como estou fazendo palavra por palavra, eu uso o REPLACE para fazer o UPDATE na base.

Algo assim:

```
UPDATE tabela SET DESCRICAO = REPLACE( descricao, 'ERRO', 'ACERTO' )
WHERE descricao LIKE '%ERRO%';
```

O problema disso é que se a palavra errada for parte de uma palavra maior ela será substituida indevidamente.

Por exemplo: em tenho várias descrições que contém a palavra DIVAN. E em alguns casos esta escrita incorretamente como DIVA, seu pedir para substituir DIVA por DIVAN, com o metodo acima, os errados ficarão certos e os já certos ficaram errados: DIVANN

E seu eu colocar algo assim:

```
UPDATE tabela SET DESCRICAO = REPLACE( descricao, 'ERRO', 'ACERTO' )
WHERE descricao LIKE '% ERRO %';
```

Não funcionará se a palavra estiver imediatamente no inicio ou no fim da descrição.

Em SQLServer eu posso utilizar algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE '.'  + coluna +  '.' 
LIKE '%[^a-z]parametro[^a-z]%'
```

Desse modo, mesmo que a palavra errada faça parte de uma palavra maior ela não é selecionada.

Portanto a pergunta. Qual é o equivalente disso para o Oracle?

Comment: Pode utilizar o [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm).

Comment: Porque ERRO é apenas uma palavra da DESCRICAO.

Comment: Eu tentei REGEXP_LIKE e não consegui fazer funcionar. Com ela eu consigo abrir mais o meu SELECT e não restringi-lo como preciso.

Comment: Eu mostro apenas a palavra. Exatamente para facilitar. Se houver 1000 linhas com o mesmo erro, eu preciso mostrar um erro. Ao corrigi-lo, estarei corringindo todas as linhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o  [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) passando a sua coluna e o seu regexp:

`WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (column_name, '(^|\s)ERRO(\s|$)');`

Comment: Funcionou Leonardo. Muito obrigado.